# PHP- concatenate string with iterator to get original variable name

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, iterator, concatenation

I have 20 variables with name $encode1,$encode2....,$encode20.
Now, I want to print these variable in the for loop by combining **$encode.$1** to achive variable $encode1.

Loop example:

```
for($i =1;$i<=20;$i++)
{
    $echo = $encodedImage.$i; => What to do here?
}
```

How could I access the names by using iterator? 
Plus, I don't want to create an array. I just want to access them directly dynamically.

I haven't found any answer on stackoverflow regarding this topic. If there is any, please share me the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it this way.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/802207)

```
<?php
$encoded1=10;
$encoded2=20;
$encoded3=30;

for($i =1;$i<=3;$i++)
{
    echo ${"encoded".$i};
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm!

Answer (score 3):

using [variables variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to achieve such a approach

> Sometimes it is convenient to be able to have variable variable names.
>   That is, a variable name which can be set and used dynamically. A
>   normal variable is set with a statement such as:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    $myVariable = "encoded" . $i;
    echo $$myVariable;
}
```